# Segmentation Fault(Core dump), Do not know why

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, char, segmentation-fault

I was trying to make up a code that I saw for some distributed application to see its working, but I am getting an error. I am trying to see the working of messages

The code is

```
class Address {
public:
char addr[6];
Address() {}
Address(string address) {
    size_t pos = address.find(":");
    int id = stoi(address.substr(0, pos));
    short port = (short)stoi(address.substr(pos + 1, address.size()-pos-1));
    memcpy(&addr[0], &id, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&addr[4], &port, sizeof(short));
    }
};



enum MsgTypes{
    JOINREQ,
    JOINREPLY,
    DUMMYLASTMSGTYPE,
    HEARTBEAT
};

/**
 * STRUCT NAME: MessageHdr
 *
 * DESCRIPTION: Header and content of a message
 */
typedef struct MessageHdr {
    enum MsgTypes msgType;
}MessageHdr;

    typedef struct en_msg {
        // Number of bytes after the class
        int size;
        // Source node
        Address from;
        // Destination node
        Address to;
    }en_msg;



void send(Address *myaddr, Address *toaddr, char *data, int size);
    int main()
    {
        MessageHdr *msg;
        size_t msgsize = sizeof(MessageHdr) + sizeof(Address) + sizeof(long) + 1;
        int id=233;
        short  port =22;
        long heartbeat=1;
        string s=to_string(id)+to_string(port);
        string s1=to_string(id+1)+to_string(port+1);
        Address *addr= new Address(s);
        Address *toaddr= new Address(s);
        msg->msgType = JOINREQ;
        memcpy((char *)(msg+1), addr, sizeof(addr));
        memcpy((char *)(msg+1) + 1 + sizeof(addr), (char *)heartbeat, sizeof(long));
        send(addr, toaddr, (char *)msg,  msgsize);
    }

    void send(Address *myaddr, Address *toaddr, char *data, int size) {
        en_msg *em;
        static char temp[2048];

        em = (en_msg *)malloc(sizeof(en_msg) + size);
        em->size = size;

        memcpy(&(em->from), &(myaddr), sizeof(em->from));
        memcpy(&(em->to), &(toaddr), sizeof(em->from));
        memcpy(em + 1, data, size);
        cout<<em;
    }
```

The error is just this line :

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Is it a run-time or a compile-time error?

Comment: If you have GDB, debug it and give us a line number please.

Comment: gdb or at least use print statements to triage the code down to a line that fails. Too much code and too complex to expect someone to take a long long time analyzing it to find a problem, if there's enough information shown to even arrive at the answer.

Comment: You might have seen a compiler warning that looked something like `uninitialized local variable 'msg' used`.  You should fix that, it's important.

Answer (score 0):

1) as Retired Ninja said in comments, first line of `main` must be like

```
   MessageHdr *msg = new MessageHdr();
```

because `msg->msgType = JOINREQ;` will cause an error with unassigned `msg`.

2) the first fix will not help because of expressions like

```
 (char *)(msg+1)
```

here `msg` of type `MessageHdr *` used as `char *` in address arithmetic. I mean that it is dangerous to calculate addresses by expression of style

```
 (char *)(msg+1) + 1
```

while `msg` is of `MessageHdr*` type, `(msg+1)` - means a shift to next structure `MessageHdr` and the additional `+1` after casting to `char*` means shift to one byte. Personally I cannot understand the logic, whereas `MessageHdr` structure has only one `enum` field and with so strange address manipulation you are trying to fit instance of `Address` class (or `long int` value) to that structure with `memcpy`.

**Conclusion:**

Very substantial program redesign is needed with writing comments and using clear logic in operations.